# Downloading file via HTTPS using QNetworkAccessManager: How to authenticate?

Tags: windows, qt, authentication, https, qnetworkaccessmanager

The general answer you can find everywhere is to use the Signal `authenticationRequired(QNetworkReply*, QAuthenticator*)`, then fill the login credentials into the given QAuthenticator object.

However, this does not work in my case as that signal is never emitted. Reason: The server does not return an authorization failure but redirects me to a login page instead. So my program will just download that page.

I have found out how to catch this by checking the attribute `QNetworkRequest::RedirectionTargetAttribute` of the QNetworkReply.
So I can detect the redirection and ask the user for auth info.

But... where do I go from there? How do I set the authentication data? Can I manually set a QAuthenticator to my QNetworkRequest or my QNetworkAccessManager? I didn't find a way to do that anywhere, just via the above-mentioned signal/slot mechanism which does not work because it does not trigger.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From documentation,

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qauthenticator.html

> QAuthenticator supports the following authentication methods:
>
> - Basic
> - NTLM version 2
> - Digest-MD5

Since you are getting redirected to a login page, and you haven't indicated if any of the above authentication methods even works, I will **assume** that it does not because things like Basic authentication is sent on every request to the server. Login pages generally authenticate the client and use some sort of a cookie for future authentication. To do this,

1. Detect login page
2. Pass proper credentials to the server (based on what the form wants)
3. In the QNetworkReply to the login page, look for cookies (Set-Cookie headers).
4. Pass the relevant cookies back with your requests.
5. If it works, you are no longer redirected to login page.

For information on cookies, you can get overview via [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Structure), but for implementation, you need to look at the [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265),

If this is incorrect, and you can use basic authentication, then that information is passed in the URL itself. Set username and password in your QUrl and if it works, you will not be redirected. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qurl.html#setPassword

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess I could build something you suggest taylored to _one_ server and login form ("2. Pass proper credentials to the server based on what the form wants"). But that is not really a satisfactory solution as I want it to work generically with any https connection.
As to the auth methods: I tried just passing basic authentication with the url, which does not work. As to NTLM 2 and Digest-MD5, I don't even know... I cannot try because I have no way to pass my auth info to the server.

Comment: OK, I ended up doing _almost_ what you suggested, except instead of doing a POST to the server with the needed login credentials - which would be hard to do because that POST would have to be tailored specially to the login page's needs - I use a QWebView (with my QNetworkAccessManager attached) to just display the login page itself. The user must log in, then I can get the cookie from the Access Manager's QNetworkCookieJar and pass it along a new download request.
It should work for pretty much any page because I'm using the original login mechanism.
Thanks again for your help!